# why Docker on Windows 10 after upgrade error?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, upgrade

Docker stopped running after upgrading to Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086 . At first, there was a long inscription Docker desktop starting, after Docker stopped. Updated through the built-in interface of the docker itself.

Windows 10

tried it :

- dism / Online /Enable-Feature: Microsoft-Hyper-V /All
- bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto

When trying:

- docker service rollback my-service = error (Error response from daemon: open \.\pipe\docker_engine_linux: The system cannot find the file specified.)

Comment: We can't guess what's going on on your machine. You haven't provided any information. Did you check any logs?  This isn't a programming question either. Finally, executing commands at random will only cause damage, not fix anything.

Comment: For example, why assume Hyper-V has anything to do with Docker? Docker was already installed and working. And if Docker isn't running now, how could any `docker` command work? There's no engine running on the other side